# Изменение фона label с помощью listwidget pyqt5

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5

у меня есть код простенького приложения, в котором натянут `label` по низ всех слоев - черного цвета.

Еще есть функция - при нажатии на кнопку, на которой написано **"меню"** открывается `listwidget`. В **"меню"**  я попытался сделать такую функцию, чтобы при нажатии `"Светлая тема"` в `lsitwidget` фон `label` на главном окне меняется на `белый`.

Я хочу сделать так, чтобы после нажатия `"светлая тема"` этот текст в `listwidget` заменялся на `"темная тема"` и после клика на `"темная тема"` фон изменялся обратно на черный. Как это сделать?

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1098, 600)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(1098, 600))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(1098, 600))
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(340, 310, 441, 131))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 61, 23))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1101, 601))
        self.label.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);")
        self.label.setText("")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.frame1 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.frame1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(-1, -1, 321, 601))
        self.frame1.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame1.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame1.setObjectName("frame1")
        self.frame2 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.frame2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1101, 601))
        self.frame2.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame2.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame2.setObjectName("frame2")
        self.label.raise_()
        self.pushButton.raise_()
        self.pushButton_2.raise_()
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "меню"))


class ListWidget(QtWidgets.QListWidget):
    def itClicked(self, item):
        QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(
            None, 
            "ListWidget", 
            "click: {}".format(item.text())
        )


class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.pushButton_2.setCheckable(True) 
        self.pushButton_2.click()
        self.pushButton_2.installEventFilter(self)

        self.listWidget = ListWidget()     
        self.listWidget.insertItem(0, "Светлая тема")
        self.listWidget.insertItem(1, "Настройки")
        self.listWidget.insertItem(2, "Справка")

        self.listWidget.itemClicked.connect(self.openWindow)

        self.listWidget.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.listWidget.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.listWidget.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.listWidget.setFont (QFont ("Helvetica", 20)); 
        self.listWidget.setStyleSheet("QListWidget::item:hover {background: rgba(158, 158, 158, 40);}\n"
"QListWidget::item:selected {background: transparent;}\n"
"QListWidget::item:selected {color: black;}\n"
"")

        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.frame2)
        lay.addWidget(self.listWidget)
        lay.setContentsMargins(0, 30, 0, 0)

        self._animation = QtCore.QPropertyAnimation(self.frame2, b'size', self)
        self._animation.setStartValue(QtCore.QSize(0, self.height()))
        self._animation.setEndValue(QtCore.QSize(200, self.height()))
        self._animation.setDuration(200)     

    def eventFilter(self, watched, event):
        if self.pushButton_2 is watched:
            if event.type() == 2 and self.pushButton_2.isChecked(): 
                self.frame2.raise_()
                self.pushButton_2.raise_()
                self._animation.setDirection(QtCore.QAbstractAnimation.Forward)
                self._animation.start()
            if event.type() == 2 and (not self.pushButton_2.isChecked()):
                self._animation.setDirection(QtCore.QAbstractAnimation.Backward)
                self._animation.start()
        return super(ExampleApp,self).eventFilter(watched, event)

    def openWindow(self, item):                                  
        self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()

        if item.text() == "Светлая тема":
            self.label.setStyleSheet("background-color: white;")


if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = ExampleApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
....
    def openWindow(self, item):
# ?        self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()

        if item.text() == "Светлая тема":
            self.label.setStyleSheet("background-color: white;")
            self.listWidget.removeItemWidget(item)
            self.listWidget.takeItem(0)
            self.listWidget.setCurrentRow(0)
            self.listWidget.insertItem(0, "Темная тема")

        if item.text() == "Темная тема":   
            self.listWidget.removeItemWidget(item)
            self.listWidget.takeItem(0)
            self.listWidget.setCurrentRow(0)
            self.listWidget.setCurrentRow(0) 
            self.listWidget.insertItem(0, "Светлая тема")
            self.label.setStyleSheet("background-color: black;")
...
```

---

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1098, 600)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(1098, 600))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(1098, 600))
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(340, 310, 441, 131))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")

        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 61, 23))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1101, 601))
        self.label.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);")
        self.label.setText("")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")

        self.frame1 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.frame1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(-1, -1, 321, 601))
        self.frame1.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame1.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame1.setObjectName("frame1")

        self.frame2 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.frame2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1101, 601))
        self.frame2.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame2.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame2.setObjectName("frame2")

        self.label.raise_()
        self.pushButton.raise_()
        self.pushButton_2.raise_()
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "меню"))


class ListWidget(QtWidgets.QListWidget):
    def itClicked(self, item):
        QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(
            None, 
            "ListWidget", 
            "click: {}".format(item.text())
        )


class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.pushButton_2.setCheckable(True) 
        self.pushButton_2.click()
        self.pushButton_2.installEventFilter(self)

        self.listWidget = ListWidget()     
        self.listWidget.insertItem(0, "Светлая тема")
        self.listWidget.insertItem(1, "Настройки")
        self.listWidget.insertItem(2, "Справка")

        self.listWidget.itemClicked.connect(self.openWindow)

        self.listWidget.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.listWidget.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.listWidget.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.listWidget.setFont (QFont ("Helvetica", 20)); 
        self.listWidget.setStyleSheet("QListWidget::item:hover {background: rgba(158, 158, 158, 40);}\n"
"QListWidget::item:selected {background: transparent;}\n"
"QListWidget::item:selected {color: black;}\n"
"")

        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.frame2)
        lay.addWidget(self.listWidget)
        lay.setContentsMargins(0, 30, 0, 0)

        self._animation = QtCore.QPropertyAnimation(self.frame2, b'size', self)
        self._animation.setStartValue(QtCore.QSize(0, self.height()))
        self._animation.setEndValue(QtCore.QSize(200, self.height()))
        self._animation.setDuration(200)     

    def eventFilter(self, watched, event):
        if self.pushButton_2 is watched:
            if event.type() == 2 and self.pushButton_2.isChecked(): 
                self.frame2.raise_()
                self.pushButton_2.raise_()
                self._animation.setDirection(QtCore.QAbstractAnimation.Forward)
                self._animation.start()
            if event.type() == 2 and (not self.pushButton_2.isChecked()):
                self._animation.setDirection(QtCore.QAbstractAnimation.Backward)
                self._animation.start()
        return super(ExampleApp,self).eventFilter(watched, event)

    def openWindow(self, item):
# ?        self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()

        if item.text() == "Светлая тема":
            self.label.setStyleSheet("background-color: white;")
            self.listWidget.removeItemWidget(item)
            self.listWidget.takeItem(0)
            self.listWidget.setCurrentRow(0)
            self.listWidget.insertItem(0, "Темная тема")

        if item.text() == "Темная тема":   
            self.listWidget.removeItemWidget(item)
            self.listWidget.takeItem(0)
            self.listWidget.setCurrentRow(0)
            self.listWidget.setCurrentRow(0) 
            self.listWidget.insertItem(0, "Светлая тема")
            self.label.setStyleSheet("background-color: black;")


if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = ExampleApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]